# CSS - Grid Display not taking up full width of container

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I just started using grids to make a responsive website, and ran into some issues. It seems like my grid does not take up the entire width of my container, even though i specified for width to be 100%, margin and padding to be 0. I googled around and realised that an orange indication on the 'inspect elements' referred to 'border'. However, I am not sure how to get rid of it, and make my container take the full remaining width of my screen. All help is appreciated, thank you!

Here is the css (the > 1200px one is shown as that is the one shown in the screenshot below)

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

    .container {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 20% auto;
        grid-template-rows: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        border: none;
    }
    
    .card-col {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-row-start: 1;
    }
    
    .tabs-col {
        grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-row-start: 1;
    }

}
```

Here is my JSX (im using React)

```
<div className='container'>
    <div className='card-col'>
        <ProjectCard project={project} />}
    </div>

    <div className='tabs-col'>
         .... (not including this as there are lots of stuff within this)
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using AntD for my UI package, but I am doing the responsive breakpoint by myself, would there be any conflict due to that?

Here is a screenshot of the issue I am facing

[image]

I am new to CSS in general, so do guide me along if there are any better ways to handle the layout! Thank you!

Comment: Change `grid-template-columns: 20% auto;` to `grid-template-columns: 20% 1fr;` https://alligator.io/css/css-grid-layout-fr-unit/

Comment: i changed it to 1fr but the same issue is still there, is there any reason why there is a 'border' for my container?

Comment: That area doesn't look like border, I'd say that is margin. Can you add css which is applied before `@media`?

Comment: okay i changed the classname from container to some other class name and it worked, thank you :-) i think there was some other inteference from the container classname